# Roles missing in Chef Manager, but present when roles listed in console

Tags: chef

I created a series of roles directly in Chef Manager. When I refreshed the page, the roles were gone. They are still on the server, as shown when I run the `knife role list` command in ChefDK.

Is there some setting I need to adjust?

[image]

Interestingly, if I type "https://chefmanager.website.com/organizations/*org*/roles/*rolename*" into the URL bar, the role appears back on the list, and I can edit it. Then I refresh, and it's hidden again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to low storage on the machine hosting Chef Server and Chef Manage (particularly the log directory). Logs were cleared, and service returned to normal. I still had to go to each roll URL to reload it into the list.